# A jQuery clock where I can set the initial time and then let it run client side

Tags: jquery, clock

I'd like to set the time at the top of my site and have it constantly update itself, only client side.

So on the initial page load, I'd give it the server time:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTime()
{
    return Content(@DateTime.Now.AddHours(3).ToString("HH:mm"));
    //Returns something like: "20:05"
}
```

Then I'd like the client to just start running a clock starting from the time I've given it.

So when a user loads the page, he recieves `20:05` and without regarding his own local time, I'd like that clock to move forward in a regular fashion. `20:06`, `20:07`, etc.

Is there something like this available for jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of incrementing a number on a page by 1 every second: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3VW/

Is that enough for you to work with?

Comment: Better documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: I need something where I can set the time and have it advance in a normal clock like fashion.

Comment: Javascript will return the time on the client, not the server.

Comment: @RET: I realize that. That is not the functionality I'm looking for. I want to give the "clock" object a starting time, then have it advance in time starting from that.